# Type Provider for Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, f#, f#-3.0, type-providers

Would it be possible to create a type provider in F# 3.0 for Entity Framework, so that I can get neat IntelliSense like with the SqlDataConnection (included in Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders) but with EF under the hood?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They already provide two Entity Framework type providers out of the box. The [EdmxFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361038%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) type provider for disconnected EDMX files, and the [SqlEntityConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361035%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) type provider for live database connections (the latter being akin to the `SqlDataConnection` type provider).